# Salesforce Marketing Cloud Field Level Encryption for Mobile Number

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, field-level-encryption

We are planning to enable Field Level Encryption for our Marketing Cloud Instance.
Looking at the limitations of FLE from https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_field_level_encryption_limitiations.htm&type=5, ***Field-Level Encryption doesn’t support encryption of a mobile number used as a subscriber key value.*** is mentioned as one of the limitations of FLE.

We are planning to store mobile numbers inside marketing cloud to be used in Mobile Studio for SMS sending. I wanted to know whether it is possible to encrypt the mobile numbers using FLE given that it is ***NOT*** a subscriber key. Will Marketing cloud be able to decrypt this mobile number during SMS send time?

Answer (score 0):

Field-Level Encryption is not able to decrypt mobile numbers at send-time as explained in the **[FAQ documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_faq_use_mobile_studio_with_fle.htm&type=5)**. You will need to store mobile numbers in non-encrypted format to use them.

> You can use Mobile Studio with Field-Level Encryption. Mobile Studio does not permit encryption for mobile numbers used as subscriber keys **and does not decrypt mobile numbers at send time.**